# How to share object in blade template across Zizaco/Confide routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to share an object across a Laravel application. I need this because I want to create a blade template which will be included everywhere and will also perform some logic/data manipulation (a dynamic menu sort of speak).

To be able to accomplish this I've created a constructor in the Base controller and used View::share facade.
While this works across all routes in the application, it's not working for Zizaco/Confide generated routes, where I get Undefined variable error for $books.

This is the constructor in the base controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $books = Book::all();
    View::share('books', $books);
    return View::make('adminMenu')->with('books', $books);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need are [View Composers!!](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers)

You can hook a view composer to a certain view name or pattern (using `*` wildcard). Every time before that view gets rendered the view composer will run.

*You can put this anywhere. Most elegant would be a custom `app/composers.php` which is then required at the bottom of `app/start/global.php`*

```
View::composer('adminMenu', function($view){
    $books = Book::all();
    $view->with('books', $books);
}
```